# Run Exe from WCF

Tags: c#, wcf

I am having the WCF. through WCF I want to call an exe on particular request.
that exe has arguments (path of SSL certificate file)

I have given the path correctly, but it is giving me error

> *"Could not load PFX file: An internal error occurred.  --"*

and when LoadUserProfile is enabled in the IIS getting error as

> *"Could not load PFX file: The profile for the user is a temporary profile"*

I am running the WCF with service account having the admin rights(the service account has the server admin rights)

this code is working fine in development but getting error in UAT

the code like

```
var processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    FileName = _ExePath,
    CreateNoWindow = true,
    Arguments = Arguments,
    RedirectStandardInput = true,
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    LoadUserProfile = true,
    UseShellExecute = false
};
Process process = new Process { StartInfo = processInfo };

process.Start();
string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
process.StandardInput.Close();
process.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: Post the code which is throwing an error as well as any contextual code which may be helpful to those who wish to help you.

Comment: Running WCF using an account with admin rights is asking for major security problems...

Comment: error call stack please. the exe might be loaded?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "running WCF with admin permission". did you do this by 1) IIS app, 2) (IIS) app pool for your app, 3) WCF running stand-alone, 4) NT services?

Comment: Also, look in your NT Event Logs (Application, System) and see if those have more information about the error.

Comment: I have has issues in the past with WCF where my code worked fine in development but when I tried to run it on an actual server, the permissions were locked down.  My problem had to do with impersonation but you might be running into similar.

Comment: _"...this code is working `fine in development` but getting error in UAT..."_ - 1) that's why you should `always` develop and run projects that are meant to be Windows Services `as` Windows Services rather than say a console app.  2)  Anything that requires a certain account should be DEV-tested in a VM rather than your DEV box